# Why are there 3 level of SSL certificates from Browser?

Tags: ssl, https

When I open the SSL details of an internal application inside network (Intranet enterprise application) - I see 3 levels of certificates? What does each level mean?

[image: elve]

Comment: my bad, it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific definition of each "level".

The HTTPS world works using a PKIX model: each entity (here specifically website and their hostname) is authenticated by some X.509 certificate.

For the trust to happen this server certificate needs to be signed by another certificate, called an authority certificate that you trust.

Browsers are shipped with hundreds of default authority certificates. The system is built under the assumption that you trust the entities behind those certificates fully (yes, without having at any point seen all this list or explicitely given consent; you can remove all of them from your browser's or even OS trust store but then you will not be able anymore to connect anywhere through HTTPS and you will need to re-add them one by one), which means you accept as valid (besides other technical checks like on dates, etc.) any certificate signed by these authority certificates.

But for multiple technical and non technical reasons, authorities often do not sign end certificates directly but uses intermediary certificates (the "middle" level in your case if you want).

It does not change anything from the model above as the trust flows from the root and when you connect to a server it is responding with its own certificate plus any other intermediaries needed to reach back any trusted root.

Note that the depth may vary. Some authorities may issue end certificate directly (so you will have 2 "levels" in the output), some may use one intermediary (frequent case), some may use a cascade of intermediaries (intermediaries through some technical points in their certificate can be restricted to sign only some specific certificates like under specific names and so on), this is all up the certificate authority that issued the given end certificate you are looking at.

And when you deal with "self-signed" certificates, you do not have levels anymore because the certificate is signed by itself which means it is its own certificate authority, so it is alone in the list of certificates.